# How to call jQuery functions from my form with Ajax?

Tags: 8, forms, javascript, ajax

There is an ajax callback which occurs on change of a field in my drupal 8 form.  This populates a wrapper with information from the server.  however I also want to excecute a jquery command to make the visibility of another field be visible after that .  How can this be done?

I tried this  `$form['ajax-wrapper']['#attributes'] = array('visibility'=>'initial');`

but that doesnt have any effect I need to be able to run this jquery command or this javascript but dont know how to trigger it after the ajax

```
document.getElementById( 'ajax-wrapper' ).style.visibility = 'initial';

           $("#ajax-wrapper").show();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read the documentation as you are conflating the idea of `ajax` and what the AJAX capability of Form API is. A form item needs to add an `#ajax` item to perform `ajax` callbacks (php), and those functions can trigger AJAX commands *some of which* can trigger external JS functions.

On top of that, your actual JS code needs to conform to Drupal JS / behavior format so that it is leveraged by Drupal properly. The minimum here is it at least has to be [enclosed in an anonymous function to prevent a jQuery conflict](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/standards/javascript/javascript-coding-standards):

```
/**
 * @file
 */
(function ($) {

  "use strict";

  // All the JavaScript for this file.
  $("#ajax-wrapper").show();
  // other code or behaviors

})(jQuery);
```

Plus, if you have form fields that are dependent on other fields as far as being *visible*, you might be able to just use `#states`.

Here are resources:

- https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module
- [Behaviors](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview)
- [AJAX API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/group/ajax/8.2.x)
- [Ajax Forms in Drupal 8](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-ajax-forms-drupal-8/)
- [AJAX command usage example](https://gist.github.com/AkshayKalose/37df41d94d16ee1eec35)
- [InvokeCommand](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Ajax%21InvokeCommand.php/class/InvokeCommand/8.2.x)
- [Form API #states](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/form-api-states)
- [Using InvokeCommand](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/205997/ajax-invokecommand-with-custom-callback-primary-tabs-viewactive-tab)